# autodesk-forge problems with auth

Tags: authentication, autodesk-forge

How to solve problem with client_id??

I write this $node node AuthTokenServer.js

And the answer after go to browser and write, "localhost:5000/"
is `I'm alive!`

Then I test, "localhost:5000/auth" and the answer is ...

```
AuthTokenServer: getting PRODUCTION token...
{ "developerMessage":"The client_id specified does not have access to the api product","userMessage":"","errorCode":"AUTH-001","more info":"......}
```

Well I search in several post but I didn't find anything.

Anyone could help me?

I see tipical errors autodesk API

http://autodesk-test.apigee.net/documentation/v1/errors/errors.html

But I don't know how is the problem with my API product.

Thank you

Comment: When you create a new App on the portal, you can select which API's the generated keys give you access too. You could maybe put a snippet that shows what code you are running in AuthTokenServer.js ...

Comment: It is true. I add all apis availables but it doesn't work well. I have now activated 3D Print API, Data Management API, BIM 360 API, Design Automatio API and Model Derivate API. On the other hand I have two apps and regenerate some times its.

Comment: the "I'm alive" response is the standard PHP page, it's expected. About the error, we'll need more information, like the Forge endpoint you're calling. Can you add that piece of code? Here is a quick v1 sample http://adndevblog.typepad.com/cloud_and_mobile/2016/01/quick-and-simple-php-view-and-data-sample.html

Comment: Well the Forge endpoint is following: http://127.0.0.1:5000/auth  I write it in browser like step  9) of this  github ;      https://github.com/GetSomeRest/AuthTokenServer_Simple          and the answer is { "developerMessage":"The client_id specified does not have access to the api product","userMessage":"","errorCode":"AUTH-001","more info":"http://developer.api.autodesk.com/documentation/v1/errors/AUTH-001"}

Comment: I test with other endpoints like http://localhost:5000/auth-stg and http://localhost:5000/auth-dev but response is the same.

Comment: <code>    // Call the Autodesk authentication API to get a token based on our client_id and client_secret.
    // the token.
    var clientId = "-------------";
    var clientSecret = "----------";

    function getAuthCode(mainResponse, baseUrl, clientId, clientSecret) {
    //  var dataString = "client_id=" + clientId + "&client_secret=" +     clientSecret + "&grant_type=client_credentials";
     var dataString = "client_id=" + clientId + "&client_secret=" +     clientSecret + "&grant_type=client_credentials";
</code>

Comment: Sorry I try to indent like code but I don't understand how??

Comment: can you edit your question with the code you're trying?

Comment: Thanks Augusto! I try with your sample and it work fine. http://adndevblog.typepad.com/cloud_and_mobile/2016/01/quick-and-simple-php-view-and-data-sample.html.

Comment: Sorry. It is solved. Thanks for yours help

Answer (score 0):

For the record, from the discussion on the question, here is a PHP sample for View and Data avaiable at [this blog post](http://adndevblog.typepad.com/cloud_and_mobile/2016/01/quick-and-simple-php-view-and-data-sample.html).

```
<?php
// we need a REST Library, found HttpFul
// Download from http://phphttpclient.com/
// You may need to add permissions for MAC OS with Apache
//     sudo chmod -R 755 /library/webserver/documents
//     (assuming default folder)
include 'httpful.phar';

// define some constants for this quick sample
define(CONSUMER_KEY, "your key");
define(CONSUMER_SECRET, "your secret");
define(BASE_URL, 'https://developer.api.autodesk.com');

// if the request URL contains the method being requested
// for instance, a call to view.and.data.php/authenticate
// will redirect to the function with the same name
$apiName = explode('/', trim($_SERVER['PATH_INFO'],'/'))[0];
if (!empty($apiName)){
    // get the function by API name
    try{ $apiFunction = new ReflectionFunction($apiName);}
    catch (Exception $e) { echo ('API not found');}

    // run the function and 'echo' it's reponse
    if ($apiFunction != null) echo $apiFunction->invoke();

    exit(); // no HTML output
}

// now the APIs
function authenticate(){
    // request body (client key & secret)
    $body = sprintf('client_id=%s' . 
                    '&client_secret=%s' . 
                    '&grant_type=client_credentials',
                    CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET);

    // prepare a POST request following the documentation
    $response = 
        \Httpful\Request::post(
          BASE_URL . '/authentication/v1/authenticate')
        ->addHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded')
        ->body($body)
        ->send(); // make the request

    if ( $response->code == 200)
        // access the JSON response directly
        return $response->body->access_token; 
    else
        // something went wrong...
        throw new Exception('Cannot authenticate');
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>Minimum PHP View and Data Sample</title>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://developer.api.autodesk.com/viewingservice/v1/viewers/style.css" />
</head>
<script src="https://developer.api.autodesk.com/viewingservice/v1/viewers/viewer3D.min.js?v=1.2.23"></script>
<script>
// This is the basic JavaScript sample code available at the documentation
// It's optimized for 3D models and slightly adjusted for this case

// Show the model specified on the URN parameter
function showModel() {
    var options = {
        'document': 'urn:' + document.getElementById('modelURN').value,
        'env': 'AutodeskProduction',
        'getAccessToken': getToken,
        'refreshToken': getToken,
    };
    var viewerElement = document.getElementById('viewer');
    var viewer = new Autodesk.Viewing.Viewer3D(viewerElement, {});
    Autodesk.Viewing.Initializer(
        options,
        function () {
            viewer.initialize();
            loadDocument(viewer, options.document);
        }
    );
}

// Load the document (urn) on the view object
function loadDocument(viewer, documentId) {
    // Find the first 3d geometry and load that.
    Autodesk.Viewing.Document.load(
        documentId,
        function (doc) { // onLoadCallback
            var geometryItems = [];
            geometryItems = Autodesk.Viewing.Document.getSubItemsWithProperties(doc.getRootItem(), {
                'type': 'geometry',
                'role': '3d'
            }, true);
            if (geometryItems.length > 0) {
                viewer.load(doc.getViewablePath(geometryItems[0]));
            }
        },
        function (errorMsg) { // onErrorCallback
            alert("Load Error: " + errorMsg);
        }
    );
}

// This calls are required if the models stays open for a long time and the token expires
function getToken() {
    return makePOSTSyncRequest("view.and.data.php/authenticate");
}

function makePOSTSyncRequest(url) {
    var xmlHttp = null;
    xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlHttp.open("POST", url, false);
    xmlHttp.send(null);
    return xmlHttp.responseText;
}
</script>
<body>
    <div>This is a minimum sample in PHP5.
        <br /> First edit this file and enter your consumer key and consumer secret. Request at <a href="http://forge.autodesk.com">Forge portal</a>.
        <br /> To use this sample you need a model URN. Please upload a model at <a href="http://models.autodesk.io">Models.Autodesk.IO</a></div>
    <hr />
    <div>
        Specify a model URN:
        <input type="text" id="modelURN" />
        <input type="button" value="View model" onclick="showModel()">
    </div>
    <hr />
    <div id="viewer">
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```